# Stop export process in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I stop the export process in SQL Developer?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Pressing the Cancel Task button?

[image]

If you have hit the Run in Background button you can go to Menu: View -> Task Progres and there will be the export. You can hit the red Cancel Task button.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the Results Panel Cancel Button
2. Disconnect Connections/Kill session